# indexedDb , Storing/updating Objects with set interval to use in web workers.-(memory leak)

Tags: data-structures, indexeddb, web-worker

***Question***: How come the code represented below creates a memory leak

**Note**: My objective is to store updated objects every frame so i can sync these 
objects with web workers.

**Disclaimer**: I am using set interval with it on purpose and if I had any other way of transfering this amount of objects over post-message I would.

**Alternative**:So if you have a alternative method that can store the given array of objects with randomized values that are a collection of integers and strings, please make an example I would be just as thrilled and others would appreciate a way to finally get rid of this dillemma thank you :)++.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">


    const dbName = "the_name";
    var version=85;
    var storeName= "store85";
    var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, version);
let db
    request.onsuccess= function(event){
        db = event.target.result;
//open database


setInterval(build,1000/24)


    };

    request.onerror = function(event) {
        // Handle errors.
    };
    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        let db = event.target.result;


        let objectStore = db.createObjectStore(storeName, {autoIncrement:true});


        // Use transaction oncomplete to make sure the objectStore creation is
        // finished before adding data into it.
        objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {

            let customerObjectStore = db.transaction(storeName, "readwrite").objectStore(storeName);

//Initial add option here if prefered instead of if statements in open.



        }
    };



function build() {

    var customerData = [];

    for(let i=0;i<=50000;i++){
        customerData.push({"minX":Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1),"minY":Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1),"maxX":Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1),"maxY":0,"id":Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1)})
    }



    window.t0 = performance.now();
    let transaction = db.transaction( storeName,"readwrite").objectStore(storeName);
        let additem =transaction.put(customerData);
        additem.onsuccess= function (event){

                window.t1 = performance.now();//alert(window.t1-window.t0);




        }

}

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**The Reason**: As it stands now reletively no one now uses web workers.The post message system is great , but it does little to nothing other than give way for processing things like image blobs and even then its using a dirty method. My way still uses a dirty method but increases the amount of information to pass ,by 10 fold , making way for reasonability to use web workers and not only that , but to make a global scope that can have as many variables as wanted and not use ram. Only flaw so far is the inconsistancy between updates due to harddrive disc read speed and failed requests and such. In all this method works so far as demonstrated , the only thing wrong so far is the memory leak. I do believe if this is solved then libraries like thread.js can use it in their code to not only inline code but dynamically share data across threads.